# 3-term recurrence relation including integral or differential operator for polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, recurrences, orthogonal-polynomials

Sequences of polynomials with a 3-term recurrence relations are well known for orthogonal polynomials. Do recurrence relations using differential or integral operators also appear in some theories?

I have encountered a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ of degree $2n$ with
$$p_{n+1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}I^2\left(x\cdot p_n(x)\right)+I\left(\frac{1}{x^2}I^3\left(\left(1+\frac{x}{4}\right)\cdot p_{n-1}(x)\right)\right),$$
where $I(x^n)=\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ is the integral operator.

Have any families of polynomials with similar recurrences been studied? Note, that the upper formula can be rewritten using a differential operator.

#### Background

In my case the polynomials appear as moments of a stochastic process: $\mathbb{E}(X^{2n}_t)=p_n(t)$

I has started with a (moment) generating function
$$exp(xz){}_1F_1(1-z,2,xz)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(x)z^{2n}$$
This leads to the explicit formula
$$p_n(x)=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\theta(3n-k+1,k-n+1)}{(3n-k)!(3n-k+1)!}x^n,$$
where $\theta(n,m)$ are Areatangenshyperbolicus numbers
$$\dfrac{1}{m!}\left(2Artanh\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)\right)^m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\theta(n,m)\frac{z^n}{n!}.$$
A recurrence relation for the numbers has led me to the relation for the polynomials.

Comment: have you tried some nice initial conditions, and looked for hits in the OEIS for the coefficients?